# increase gradually the address of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am a new student in c programming, and I made a small program to see in the action, all the combinations of ++ in the pointers. So I codded: (i run it in Ubuntu via virtualbox)

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 main()
 {
    int num = 1;
    int  *p = &num;

    printf("\nnum position: %p num value: %d\n", p, num);

    *p += 1;
    printf("\n---- *p += 1; -----\n");
    printf("num position: %p num value: %d\n", p, num);

    *p++;
    printf("\n---- *p++; -----\n");
    printf("num position: %p num value: %d\n", p, num);

    (*p)++;
    printf("\n---- (*p)++; -----\n");
    printf("num position: %p num value: %d\n", p, num);

    ++(*p);
    printf("\n---- ++(*p); -----\n");
    printf("num position: %p num value: %d\n", p, num);

    ++*p;
    printf("\n---- ++*p; -----\n");
    printf("num position: %p num value: %d\n\n", p, num);

 }
```

**Output:**

```
num position: 0xbfce07b8 num value: 1

---- *p += 1; -----
num position: 0xbfce07b8 num value: 2

---- *p++; -----
num position: 0xbfce07bc num value: 2

---- (*p)++; -----
num position: 0xbfce07bd num value: 2

---- ++(*p); -----
num position: 0xbfce08bd num value: 2

---- ++*p; -----
num position: 0xbfce08bd num value: 2
```

I have understood the different usage of ++. However my question is about the addresses (i just write the 4 digits)
 
 At first the address is : **07b8**
 after the 1st    increment the address is **07bc** (increased by 4 (HEX) )
 after the 2nd increment the address is **07bd** (increased by 1 (hex))
 after the 3nd increment the address is **08bd** (increased by 100 (hex))
Why the increment of the address isn't stable?

Comment: Dont forget to add return 0; at the end of your main. always use return 0 and also try to use int main() instead of just main() since c99 strictly checks the return types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior: your code cannot write to `*p` after it has been advanced, because at that point the pointer points to memory not allocated to an `int`. Because of the way your variables are declared it appears that after the first increment the pointer is actually pointing to itself! Printing the address of the pointer `&p` should confirm that.

To fix this issue, change your program as follows:

```
int data[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int *p = data;
```

Now you can increment your pointer up to ten times without the risk of writing to memory outside of the range allocated to your program.

Note: `%p` expects a `void*` pointer, so you should insert an explicit cast.

Comment: i had forgotten that %p needs (void *)&p. I changed this and the outcome has more sense now `0xbfabdf98` -> `0xbfabdf9c` -> `0xbfabdf9d`. Also the `int  p = &num;` @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Nat95 It needs `(void*)p`. When you pass `(void*)&p` you are printing the address of the pointer itself, which should stay constant throughout the program. I suggested printing `(void*)&p` to see that it gets allocated soon after `num`: after `p++` the pointer would be pointing to itself.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because generally the memory isn't allocate sequentially by the O.S. As a start you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_%28operating_systems%29).